# Displaying data into two different divs using JavaScript, after fetching it from db

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have to write JavaScript code for a web page to display some data after fetching it from database(using php/mysql). I have two divs (for results), one textfield (for entering parameter) and one button on your html page. Once clicked on the button, I need to call a ajax function which will ultimately make a request for php page on the server. The results will be passed to the client and will be used to dynamically change the contents of the divisions on the html page. You will populate one division with one type of data, other with the remaining data. I am looking to implement this using AJAX technology, PHP and DBMS.
I do not wish to use jquery.

I am looking for some help with the Javascript code.

```js
<script>
function fetchData() {
  var yr = document.getElementById('entry').value;
  if (yr.length==0) { 
    document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML="";
 return;
  }

  var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
  {
  var content = xmlhttp.responseText;
 if (content == "%<searchword>%")
  document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = content;
 else  
  document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = content; 
     }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","db.php?q="+ yr ,true);
  xmlhttp.send(); 
}
</script>
```

```html
<body>

<form>
Enter year: <input type="text" id="entry" />
<input type="button" value="check here" onclick="fetchData()" />
</form>
<div id="result1">result 1 here</div>
<div id="result2"> result 2 here</div>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: In order for us to help you with the Javascript code, you need to post it first. Then we can tell you where your mistakes are, and how to fix them.

Comment: `document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = data1; document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = data2;`

Comment: I have updated my work. Can you help me with the code ??
The php file returns a table consisting of the combined data to be shown in the divs.

Comment: What is represented in `"%<searchword>%"` ? I mean... if a table is returned with `content`...

Comment: Does the PHP return JSON? Then you need to use `content = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText)` or `content = xmlhttp.responseJSON`. Then you can process the table as a Javascript object.

Comment: that is a parameter I need to check after the data is received from the php file.

Comment: @Barmar : No, it returns a table with data.

Comment: You mean it returns an HTML table?

Comment: Yes. Is using JSON the only way to parse the contents of the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to test whether the table contains `$<searchword>%`, use `.indexOf()`

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        var content = xmlhttp.responseText;
        if (content.indexOf("%<searchword>%") != -1) {
            document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = content;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = content; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have used this function, but it doesn't separate the data. All the data gets displayed in a single div.

Comment: What's supposed to be separated? Your code puts the entire content in one div or another, depending on a condition. I think you need to put more details into the question. Show the returned table, and then show what you want to do with it.

Comment: I have added a picture with sample data and intended result. Can you please show me where my error is ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
function fetchData() {
  var yr = document.getElementById('entry').value;
  if (yr.length==0) { 
    document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML="";
    return;
  }

  var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() 
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
     {
        var content = xmlhttp.responseText;
    if (content == "%<searchword>%")
        document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = content;
    else        
        document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = content; 
     }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","db.php?q="+ yr ,true);
  xmlhttp.send(); 
}
</script>
```

```html
<body>

<form>
Enter year: <input type="text" id="entry" />
<input type="button" value="check here" onclick="fetchData()" />
</form>
<div id="result1">result 1 here</div>
<div id="result2"> result 2 here</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).